# Apply a function on a column of a dataframe depending on the value of another column and then groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Assume the dataframe with column 'A' and column 'condition' as reproduced by the code below.

```
example = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'condition': [0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,2,1]})
```

I want to multiply by 2 the values in column 'A' if the values in column 'B' are 0 or 2. So I tried these:

```
example['A']=example['A'].apply(lambda x: x*2 \
             if example['condition']==0 or example['condition']==2)

example['A']=np.where(example.condition==0 or example.condition==2, \
             lambda x: x*2, example.A)
```

but none of these work in order to get the desired output as below:

```
    output:                 desired output:
    example                 example
       A  B                          A  B
    0  0  0                      0   0  0
    1  1  1                      1   1  1
    2  2  0                      2   4  0
    3  3  1                      3   3  1
    4  4  2                      4   8  2
    5  5  0                      5  10  0
    6  6  1                      6   6  1
    7  7  2                      7  14  2 
    8  8  2                      8  16  2 
    9  9  1                      9   9  1
```

If I get the desired output, I want to groupby 'condition' and calculate the absolute summation of 'A' values  if the 'A' values are bigger than 2.5. I have this in mind, but I if I do not get the desired output from above I am not sure if it works.

```
group1=example.groupby([example[condition')['A'].\
       agg([ ('A sum' , lambda x : x[x>=2.5].abs(sum()) ])
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we get all the rows where `condition is 0 or 2`. Then we `multiply` the `A` values by two of these rows and use `GroupBy.sum` while using `query` to filter all the rows where `A >= 2.5`

```
m = example['condition'].isin([0,2])
example['A'] = np.where(m, example['A'].mul(2), example['A'])
grpd = example.query('A.ge(2.5)').groupby('condition', as_index=False)['A'].sum()
```

**Output**

```
   condition   A
0          0  28
1          1  18
2          2  76
```

---

Details `GroupBy.sum`:

First we use `query` to get all the rows where  `A >= 2.5`:

```
example.query('A.ge(2.5)')

    A  condition
2   4          0
3   3          1
4   8          2
5  10          0
6   6          1
7  14          2
8  16          2
9   9          1
```

Then we use groupby on condition to get each group of unique values, in this case all rows with `0`, `1` and `2`:

```
for _, d in grpd.groupby('condition', as_index=False):
    print(d, '\n')

    A  condition
2   8          0
5  20          0 

   A  condition
3  3          1
6  6          1
9  9          1 

    A  condition
4  16          2
7  28          2
8  32          2
```

So if we have the seperate groups, we can use `.sum` method to sum the whole `A` column:

```
for _, d in grpd.groupby('condition', as_index=False):
    print(d['A'].sum(), '\n')

28 

18 

76
```

Comment: Great, it works very good. Just a question... how does the absolute sum work here?
And a small twist... In my original dataframe, the values in column A are times (HH:MM:SS) and I want the hours (HH) to be equal to 0 or 2. How do you suggest to write this condition?

Comment: @Newbielp I added more explanation and details. See edit.

Comment: That changes your question significantly, I see this question as answered. Feel free to post a new question and this time describe your problem correctly. @Newbielp

Comment: Many many thanks...

By the way, I need to have a closer look to this query method etc. Interesting and something to study. I applied this: `grpd=example.groupby(['condition'])['A'].agg([ ('A sum' , lambda x : x[x>=2.5].abs().sum()) ])` and worked too. But definitely this query will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can use np.where to multiply the values in column 'A' by 2 if the values in column 'B' is either 0 or 2.

```
example['A'] = np.where(example['condition'].isin([0,2]), example['A']*2,example['A'])
```

To perform summation on A if condition columns satisfy the criteria, you can first include a new column in your dataframe example which states whether A is > or < than 2.5 then perform aggregation over this dataframe.

```
example['check_A'] =np.where(example['A']>2.5,1,0)
new = example.groupby(['condition','check_A'])['A'].apply(lambda c: c.abs().sum())
```

Comment: Thanks, just a quick question: how would you apply the absolute summation? I need to sum and then calculate the abs() of the sum value.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
df.loc[df['condition']%2==0, 'A'] = df['A']*2
```

O/P:

```
    A  condition
0   0          0
1   1          1
2   4          0
3   3          1
4   8          2
5  10          0
6   6          1
7  14          2
8  16          2
9   9          1
```

Comment: Thanks, I can adjust other calculations I have to do to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close in your original attempt. In particular, I would bring the condition out into its own separate function to enhance readability, and then apply the function to the data frame with `axis=1`:

```
def f(row):
    if row["condition"] == 0 or row["condition"] == 2:
        return(int(row["A"] * 2))
    return(row["A"])   # Base condition 

example['B'] = example.apply(f, axis=1)   # Apply to rows of 'example' df

example.drop("condition", axis=1, inplace=True)

example

    A   condition   B
0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1
2   2   0   4
3   3   1   3
4   4   2   8
5   5   0   10
6   6   1   6
7   7   2   14
8   8   2   16
9   9   1   9
```

Then, to apply your `groupby` operation:

```
example[example["A"] > 2.5].groupby("condition")["A"].apply(lambda x: np.sum(np.abs(x)))

condition
0     5
1    18
2    19
Name: A, dtype: int64
```