# Change the date column when the time column satisfies a certain condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timedelta

Following my initial question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57657119/apply-a-function-on-a-column-of-a-dataframe-depending-on-the-value-of-another-co) with very constructive answers, I want to customize it for my original dataframe.

The dataframe upon which I need to make changes has accrued from: `nightframe=new_df.between_time('22:00','04:00')` and the first few rows look like this:

```
                           date      time  diffs criteria 1
datetime                                                   
2018-01-05 22:00:00  2018-01-05  22:00:00    0.0       True
2018-01-05 23:00:00  2018-01-05  23:00:00   -1.0      False
2018-01-06 00:00:00  2018-01-06  00:00:00    1.0       True
2018-01-06 01:00:00  2018-01-06  01:00:00   -2.0      False
2018-01-06 02:00:00  2018-01-06  02:00:00   -1.0       True
2018-01-06 03:00:00  2018-01-06  03:00:00    1.0       True
2018-01-06 04:00:00  2018-01-06  04:00:00    1.0      False
2018-01-06 22:00:00  2018-01-06  22:00:00   -1.0       True
```

I need to assign the date to the previous date if the time is from 00:00 to 04:00. I have tried these codes for my condition and they do not work:

```
condition = nightframe['time'].isin([0,1,2,3,4])
condition = nightframe['time'].dt.time.isin(\
                      ['00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00','04:00'])
condition = nightframe['time'](['00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00','04:00'])
```

If the condition works, I suppose that the dataframe I need can be given from:  `nightframe['date']=np.where(condition, nightframe['date']-pd.Timedelta('1 day'), nightframe['date'])` and should give this view:

```
                           date      time  diffs criteria 1
datetime                                                   
2018-01-05 22:00:00  2018-01-05  22:00:00    0.0       True
2018-01-05 23:00:00  2018-01-05  23:00:00   -1.0      False
2018-01-06 00:00:00  2018-01-05  00:00:00    1.0       True
2018-01-06 01:00:00  2018-01-05  01:00:00   -2.0      False
2018-01-06 02:00:00  2018-01-05  02:00:00   -1.0       True
2018-01-06 03:00:00  2018-01-05  03:00:00    1.0       True
2018-01-06 04:00:00  2018-01-05  04:00:00    1.0      False
2018-01-06 22:00:00  2018-01-06  22:00:00   -1.0       True
2018-01-06 23:00:00  2018-01-06  23:00:00    1.0       True
2018-01-07 00:00:00  2018-01-06  00:00:00    0.0      False
2018-01-07 01:00:00  2018-01-06  01:00:00    1.0       True
2018-01-07 02:00:00  2018-01-06  02:00:00    0.0      False
2018-01-07 03:00:00  2018-01-06  03:00:00   -1.0      False
2018-01-07 04:00:00  2018-01-06  04:00:00    1.0       True
2018-01-07 22:00:00  2018-01-07  22:00:00    1.0       True
```

Note: the 'datetime' is the index of my dataframe and the types of the columns of nightframe are:

```
print(nightframe.dtypes)
date           object
time           object
diffs         float64
criteria 1     object
dtype: object

print(nightframe.index.dtype)
datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Explain your logic a bit more pls. What is the function of the columns `diffs` and `criteria` in this case? And where dod `2018-01-07` suddenly come from? Is your expected output based on your given example dataframe?

Comment: `diffs` and `criteria` columns are not to consider while the `dates` came from the `datetime` index column. What I am trying to do is to assign the time from 00:00 to 04:00 to the previous date, while datetime index will stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your contribution. Here is **the code that worked for me**

I opted for keeping the 'date' and creating 'date2' column in order to be able to compare. Otherwise, 'date' in place of 'date2' in the following:

```
hours=nightframe.index.hour
condition=hours.isin([0,1,2,3,4])
nightframe['date2']=np.where(condition, \
                    nightframe['date']-pd.Timedelta('1 day'), \
                    nightframe['date'])

print(nightframe.head(20))

Output[]:
                           date      time  diffs criteria 1       date2
datetime                                                               
2018-01-05 13:00:00  2018-01-05  13:00:00    0.0        NaN  2018-01-05
2018-01-05 14:00:00  2018-01-05  14:00:00   -1.0      False  2018-01-05
2018-01-05 15:00:00  2018-01-05  15:00:00    0.0       True  2018-01-05
2018-01-05 16:00:00  2018-01-05  16:00:00   -2.0      False  2018-01-05
2018-01-05 17:00:00  2018-01-05  17:00:00    1.0       True  2018-01-05
2018-01-05 18:00:00  2018-01-05  18:00:00    1.0      False  2018-01-05
2018-01-05 19:00:00  2018-01-05  19:00:00   -1.0      False  2018-01-05
2018-01-05 20:00:00  2018-01-05  20:00:00    0.0       True  2018-01-05
2018-01-05 21:00:00  2018-01-05  21:00:00   -2.0      False  2018-01-05
2018-01-05 22:00:00  2018-01-05  22:00:00    0.0       True  2018-01-05
2018-01-05 23:00:00  2018-01-05  23:00:00   -2.0      False  2018-01-05
2018-01-06 00:00:00  2018-01-06  00:00:00   -2.0       True  2018-01-05
2018-01-06 01:00:00  2018-01-06  01:00:00    0.0       True  2018-01-05
2018-01-06 02:00:00  2018-01-06  02:00:00   -1.0      False  2018-01-05
2018-01-06 03:00:00  2018-01-06  03:00:00    0.0       True  2018-01-05
2018-01-06 04:00:00  2018-01-06  04:00:00   -1.0      False  2018-01-05
2018-01-06 05:00:00  2018-01-06  05:00:00   -2.0      False  2018-01-06
2018-01-06 06:00:00  2018-01-06  06:00:00   -1.0       True  2018-01-06
2018-01-06 07:00:00  2018-01-06  07:00:00    0.0       True  2018-01-06
2018-01-06 08:00:00  2018-01-06  08:00:00    0.0       True  2018-01-06
```

Answer (score 0):

you can consider using again `between_time` to select the rows you want to remove a day something like:

```
nightframe[nightframe.between_time('00:00','04:00').index, 'date'] -= pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

and if this fails, you may need to convert the column date first with `pd.to_datetime`

```
nightframe['date'] = pd.to_datetime(nightframe['date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) + datetime.timedelta(days=-1) * (pd.to_datetime(df["time"])<="04:00:00")
```